# Refactor methods, asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two likely identical methods, like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateDirectory(string designId, CreateDirectoryModel model)
{

    string customerSchema = SfsHelpers.StateHelper.GetSchema();
    TemplateLibraryEntry entry = GetTemplateLibraryEntry(model.DesignId, customerSchema);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), entry.FilePath);
    model.DesignId = designId;
    model.Directories = new List<string>();
    model.Directories.Add("/");
    model.Directories.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    for (int i = 1; i < model.Directories.Count; i++) {
        model.Directories[i] = model.Directories[i].Substring(path.Length).Replace('\\', '/');
    }
    model.Directories.Sort();

    return View(model);
}
```

and this method:

```
public void GetUploadFileFolders(UploadViewModel model, string designId)
{
    string customerSchema = SfsHelpers.StateHelper.GetSchema();
    TemplateLibraryEntry entry = GetTemplateLibraryEntry(designId, customerSchema);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), entry.FilePath);
    model.DesignId = designId;
    model.Directories = new List<string>();
    model.Directories.Add("/");
    model.Directories.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    for (int i = 1; i < model.Directories.Count; i++) {
        model.Directories[i] = model.Directories[i].Substring(path.Length).Replace('\\', '/');
    }
    model.Directories.Sort();
}
```

But is it possible to combine this two methods to one method?

But how to combine this two methods?

Thank you

But how to change this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(UploadViewModel uploadViewModel)
    {
        CreateDirectoryModel model = new CreateDirectoryModel();
        try {
            GetUploadFileFolders(model, uploadViewModel.DesignId );
            //GetUploadFileFolders(uploadViewModel, uploadViewModel.DesignId);
            string validationError = null;

            bool fileUploaded = (uploadViewModel.UploadData != null) && (uploadViewModel.UploadData.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadViewModel.UploadData.FileName);

            if (ModelState.IsValid && fileUploaded) {
                var extension = Path.GetExtension(uploadViewModel.UploadData.FileName).TrimStart('.');
                if (!Seneca.SfsLib.FileSystemHelper.UploadOptInExtensions.Contains(extension)) {
                    ViewBag.Message = Resources.Entity.DesignTemplate.NotAllowedExtension;
                    return View(uploadViewModel);
                }

                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadViewModel.UploadData.FileName);

                TemplateLibraryEntry entry = GetTemplateLibraryEntry(uploadViewModel.DesignId, customerSchema);
                string folder = uploadViewModel.Directories[uploadViewModel.SelectedFolderId];
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), entry.FilePath, folder.Replace('/', '\\').Trim('\\'), fileName);


                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path)) {
                    uploadViewModel.UploadData.SaveAs(path);
                    return RedirectToAction(uploadViewModel.DesignId, "DesignTemplate/File");
                }

                validationError = Resources.Entity.DesignTemplate.FileAlreadyExists;
            }
            if (!fileUploaded)
                validationError = Resources.Entity.DesignTemplate.FileNotSelected;

            GetUploadFileFolders(model, uploadViewModel.DesignId);
            ViewBag.Message = validationError;
            return View(uploadViewModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.Current.LogMessage(LogType.Warning, StateHelper.GetSchema(), LogCategory.Sfs, "Unable to upload file: {0}", ex.ToString());
            AddDelayedNotification(Resources.Entity.DesignTemplate.FileCouldNotBeUploaded, Notification.NotificationType.Error);
        }
        return View(uploadViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Functions are reusables, you can create function and call same from both these actions.Or u can just call GetUploadFileFolders method from above action.

Comment: Yes, it's possible...at which step of this you stopped?

Comment: Depends on how the model classes are related to each other.

Comment: Thank you. But if you see, they are using two differen models: CreateDirectoryModel and UploadViewModel. So I cant use one of them for both.

Comment: You may want to create an interface that both classes implement. Then you can pass it around.

Comment: Hi fero, do you have an example of that? thank you

Comment: Even if they uses two models (and assuming you can't add a common interface) they still share 98% of code. Actually model classes are used in 3 lines of code (assignments), everything else is reusable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a property in UploadViewModel as what i see all properties are same in both :

```
public class UploadViewModel
{

    CreateDirectoryModel createModel {get;set;}
}

public void GetUploadFileFolders(CreateDirectoryModel model, string designId)
{
    string customerSchema = SfsHelpers.StateHelper.GetSchema();
    TemplateLibraryEntry entry = GetTemplateLibraryEntry(designId, customerSchema);
     var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), entry.FilePath);
     model.DesignId = designId;
     model.Directories = new List<string>();
     model.Directories.Add("/");
     model.Directories.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
     for (int i = 1; i < model.Directories.Count; i++) 
     {
        model.Directories[i] = model.Directories[i].Substring(path.Length).Replace('\\', '/');
     }

     model.Directories.Sort();

}
```

and in your action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateDirectory(string designId, CreateDirectoryModel model)
{
    GetUploadFileFolders(model,designId)
    return View(model);
}
```

and when using it for UploadViewModel you can now  do:

```
GetUploadFileFolders(model.creatModel,designId);
```

Comment: But if do that what I posted here. Then the directories are not found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interface (or a base class) that defines the parts you need for both classes:

```
public interface IMyModel
{
    string DesignId { get; set; }
    List<string> Directories { get; set; }
}
```

Your classes (or at least `CreateDirectoryModel`) must then implement the interface:

```
public class CreateDirectoryModel : IMyModel
{
    // ...
}
```

In the second method you change the parameter type to `IMyModel` like this:

```
public void GetUploadFileFolders(IMyModel model, string designId)
{
    // ...
}
```

Then you can call the second method from your first method.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateDirectory(string designId, CreateDirectoryModel model)
{
    GetUploadFileFolders(model, designId);
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It was a combination of methods

Answer (score 0):

using convention based mapper Automapper you can combine them as

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateDirectory(string designId, CreateDirectoryModel model)
    {

        string customerSchema = SfsHelpers.StateHelper.GetSchema();
        TemplateLibraryEntry entry = GetTemplateLibraryEntry(model.DesignId, customerSchema);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), entry.FilePath);
        model.DesignId = designId;
        model.Directories = new List<string>();
        model.Directories.Add("/");
        model.Directories.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
        for (int i = 1; i < model.Directories.Count; i++) {
            model.Directories[i] = model.Directories[i].Substring(path.Length).Replace('\\', '/');
        }
        model.Directories.Sort();
        //
        Mapper.CreateMap<CreateDirectoryModel,UploadViewModel>();
        var uploadmodel=Mapper.Map<UploadViewModel>(model);
        uploadmodel.Directories.Sort();
        //
        return View(model);
    }
```

however i suggest you that if these two classes are not specialized ,use one of them thereby reducing redundency